# I would like to put search bar beside a page selector

Tags: html, css

I'm newbie and I would like to know the way to put search bar beside page selector.
Here's a screenshot now :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rOIf.jpg

My desire layout :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfTV9.jpg

How can I make it? I need your help. Thanks in advance. I love you guys. :D

```
    <div class="wpf-navi <?php echo esc_attr($class) ?>">
        <div class="wpf-navi-wrap">
    <div id="wpf-widget-search" class="wpforo-widget-wrap"><form action="<?php echo wpforo_home_url() ?>" method="get">
        <?php wpforo_make_hidden_fields_from_url( wpforo_home_url() ) ?>
        <input type="text" placeholder="<?php wpforo_phrase('Search...') ?>" name="wpfs" class="wpfw-70" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['wpfs']) ? esc_attr(sanitize_text_field($_GET['wpfs'])) : '' ?>" ><input type="submit" class="wpfw-20" value="&raquo;">
                </form></div>
            <span class="wpf-page-info">
                <?php wpforo_phrase('Page') ?> <?php echo intval($paged) ?> / <?php echo intval($pages_count) ?>
            </span>
            <?php if( $paged - 1 > 0 ): $prev_url = ( ($paged - 1) == 1 ? $sanitized_current_url : sprintf($url, $paged - 1) ); ?>
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( WPF()->user_trailingslashit($prev_url) ) ?>" class="wpf-prev-button" rel="prev">
                    <i class="fas fa-chevron-left fa-sx"></i> <?php wpforo_phrase('prev') ?>
                </a>
            <?php endif ?>
            <select class="wpf-navi-dropdown" onchange="if (this.value) window.location.assign(this.value)" title="<?php esc_attr( wpforo_phrase('Select Page') ) ?>">
                <option value="<?php echo esc_url( WPF()->user_trailingslashit($sanitized_current_url) ) ?>" <?php wpfo_check($paged, 1, 'selected') ?>>1</option>
                <?php for($i = 2; $i <= $pages_count; $i++) : ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo esc_url( WPF()->user_trailingslashit( sprintf($url, $i) ) ) ?>" <?php wpfo_check($paged, $i, 'selected') ?>>
                        <?php echo $i ?>
                    </option>
                <?php endfor; ?>
            </select>
            <?php if( $paged + 1 <= $pages_count ): ?>
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( WPF()->user_trailingslashit(sprintf($url, $paged + 1) ) ) ?>" class="wpf-next-button" rel="next">
                    <?php wpforo_phrase('next') ?> <i class="fas fa-chevron-right fa-sx"></i>
                </a>
            <?php endif ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you using bootstrap?

Comment: This is not a PHP question but purely html+html. You would be better posting just html+css demo in codepen.